# How to set value for FormArray controls in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to bind a value to the FormArray controls and push the data to controls. I can set the control values but it is throwing error as

```
Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

I hope this is occurring because the value is just going as an object instead of going as an array of objects. Can anyone help me to rectify this?

I am hereby showing the demo.

HTML:

```html
<div
  class="custom-file"
  (click)="fileInput.click()"
  appDragDrop
  (onFileDropped)="uploadFile($event)"
>
  <input
    type="file"
    #fileInput
    (change)="uploadFile($event)"
    class="custom-file-input"
    id="uploadFile"
    formControlName="fileName"
  />
  <input readonly="true" type="text" id="uploadFile" />
  <!-- <p>{{ item.controls.uploadFile.value}}</p> -->
</div>
```

Ts:

```js
uploadFile(event, data) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.agentW9InfoForm.setControl(
        'w9Info',
        this.FB.group({
          fileName: file,
          taxId: data.taxId.value,
          signatureDate: data.signatureDate.value,
          businessType: data.businessType.value,
          originalFileName: file.name,
          agentW9id: data.agentW9id.value,
          agentCode: parseInt(
            this.agentbasicInfoForm.controls['agentCode'].value
          )
        })
      );

      formData.append('file', this.w9InfoDetails.value.fileName);
      console.log(formData);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-qszr7v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

Comment: On which action you are getting error?

Comment: Thanks for response, i fixed this issue by deleting content-type:application/json from the interceptor and it worked

Comment: @HiteshKansagara any idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59755967/how-to-send-screenshot-of-a-particular-div-onclick-of-share-icon-in-a-body-using